# oracle - querying NULL values in unpivot query

Tags: oracle, null, unpivot

I want to fetch records from oracle DB where column value is `NULL`. Also i am using `unpivot` in my query. Somehow `NULL` values are not getting selected because of `unpivot` keyword. Can you please help me about how to get rows for the same when using `unpivot`.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT a.emp_id, a.emp_dept, b.emp_location
  FROM employee a,
       location b UNPIVOT (emp_id
                  FOR dummy_id
                  IN (emp_id AS 'EMP_ID', last_date AS 'LAST_DATE'))
 WHERE emp_id = 123 AND b.emp_loc_id = 'india' AND b.location IS NULL;
```

Comment: Give an example of your query + sample data, in order to better understand the problem. Thanks

Comment: i cant provide data or sample query

Comment: Sorry to say, but then this question is for closing my friend. Stackoverflow is not a place to get direct solutions without providing at least a bit of information about the work you've done. You will get a lot of downvotes without this information and eventually this thread will get closed ... :-(

Comment: I am just looking for direction. Sorry but not possible to provide data

Comment: It's impossible for me to believe that you can't simplify your case to an example query, without providing information about the real one! If I have a problem (for example, I can't select null values for rows with col3 column NULL) with a query like `select col1, col2 from production_table where col3 <> 3`, I would write it like so: `select c1, c2 from sample_table where c3 <> 3` and I would get a solution like this `select c1, c2 from sample_table where c3 is null` ...

Comment: Not sure why you are not understanding ! It is a 3 page query having multiple joins and pivot , unpivot statements. Still i am providing a sample query.select a.emp_id , a.emp_dept , b.emp_location from employee a location b
unpivot (emp_id for dummy_id in (emp_id as 'EMP_ID',last_date as 'LAST_DATE'))
where   emp_id=123
and b.emp_loc_id='india'
and b.location is NULL

Comment: We're getting somewhere. So you say, the query `select count(*) from location where emp_loc_id ='india' and location is null` outputs something <> 0 ... correct? If that's correct, than write your UNPIVOT clause like so: `UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ...` and try that again.

Comment: location column has value NULL for some rows. Those are not getting returned.

Comment: What about using `UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ...` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55132):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/682aa/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id, a, b, c, d ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, NULL, 3, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ( value FOR name IN ( a, b, c, d ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/682aa/2/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME |  VALUE |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |    A |      1 |
|  1 |    B |      2 |
|  1 |    C |      3 |
|  1 |    D |      4 |
|  2 |    A |      1 |
|  2 |    B | (null) |
|  2 |    C |      3 |
|  2 |    D | (null) |
```